# Get filepath of every file that's copied from one folder to another

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, file-copy

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and
I wish to copy files from one folder to another and along with it also wish to store the filepath of each file that's being copied from folder1 to folder2 in a third file with space as a separator.

NOTE: Since cp command does not return any output so storing it in file won't work.

Any mix of commands or script is welcome which can be run through terminal.

> Please do not suggest any additional software.

Comment: _additional_ to what? To what  18.04's  `ubuntu-minimal` and its dependencies include?

Comment: yes additional to the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `find` and `cpio` can be used to recursively copy all files and subfolders from `folder1` to `folder2`. With `tee` in between you can write all file names (relative to `folder1`) into `outputfile`.

```
cd folder1 && find . -depth | tee outputfile | cpio -pdm folder2
```

The command `cd folder1` is necessary because `cpio` wants to get file names relative to the source folder.

`folder2` must be specified either absolute or relative to `folder1`.

To copy files only you could modify the `find` command:

```
... find . -type f -maxdepth 1 ...
```

Comment: why cd command ?

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX commands and assuming the names of the files and directories don't contain newline characters:

```
src=/some/dir
dst=/some/other/dir
file_list=/path/to/list.txt
(cd -P -- "$src" && find . |
  tee -- "$file_list" |
  pax -rwdpe -- "$dst")
```

The paths will be relative to the `$src` or `$dst` directories (which need to exist beforehand).

The GNU implementation of `cp` (as found on Ubuntu) has a `-v` option that makes it tell what it's doing.

```
LC_ALL=C cp -va -- "$src" "$dst" > "$file_list"
```

Will create a `list.txt` that contains something like:

```
'/some/dir' -> '/some/other/dir'
'/some/dir/file' -> '/some/other/dir/file'
[...]
```

Another option would be to use `tar` (not a standard command, but Ubuntu comes with GNU `tar` by default):

```
(cd -P -- "$src" && tar cf - .) |
  (cd -P -- "$dst" && tar xvf - > "$file_list")
```

Comment: why cd command ?

Comment: line 6: pax: command not found

Comment: @AshwaniShukla, If you did `find "$src" | pax -rwdpe "$dst"` without the `cd`, that would create some `/some/other/dir/some/dir` directory structure on the destination.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame that Ubuntu comes without `pax` (a POSIX-mandated command), and with `tar` (a very unportable command) by default.

Comment: but tar command is used to create compressed files as far as I know. Please add the explanation of the command too, it would be great.

Comment: @AshwaniShukla, `tar` is before all an archiver (though some implementations can call compressors like `xz` or `gzip` to compress the archives), like `cpio`. `pax` is POSIX effort to merge the very non-portable `cpio` and `tar` commands.

Comment: worked with `tar`. Thanks for the help :)